# Why can't I remove DOM element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a piece of my code that should simply remove an element from the HTML DOM, but it won't for some reason...

```
...
clearError(fields['server_error'][fieldUniqueId], 'server_error');
...

function clearError($field, type){
    $("#" + getErrorLabelId($field, type)).remove();
}

function getErrorLabelId($field, type){
    return ValidatorInstance.ErrorLabelIdPrefix + "-" + $field.data(ValidatorInstance.uniqueIdKey) + "-" + type;
}
```

All the functions work and return with the values that they expected. For example if I change the line from `$("#" + getErrorLabelId($field, type)).remove();` to `$("#" + getErrorLabelId($field, type)).css('background.color', 'blue');` it perfectly sets the background-color. But it won't remove. Why is that?

Comment: What does the HTML your trying to remove look like? Weirdness like this is (IME) often due to repeating id's. Id's must be unique on the page

Comment: What about setting the style to display:none?

Comment: @BradPatton I think that somewhat misses the point

Comment: `console.log("#" + getErrorLabelId($field, type))` inside `clearError` and compare it with the element you are trying to remove.

Comment: @Liam It looks like this: `<div id="vErrLbl-evc919jk-server_error" class="registration-validation-error">Some dummy error message</div>`

Comment: @Xatenev It perfectly matches. As I said it properly finds the element, I can even change the css attributes on it, but can't remove.

Comment: and that id is unique on the page? Search the markup for that id, does it match anything else?

Comment: @ACs `it perfectly sets the background-color. But it won't remove.` - your observation must be *somehow* wrong. If you can set the background color, then you can remove. Maybe its reappended to the DOM for some reason? Maybe you are looking at a different element? Maybe your changes have not been applied?

Comment: [Your code works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/h0tou75x/)

Comment: Does the browser inspector/dev tools console log out any js errors?